# elixir ecto - pass preloaded data in to embeded preloaded subquery

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have 3 tables:

- Tasks
- Users
- Reviews

`Users` will work on the `Tasks`, and will get `Reviews` for how well he did the job.
The `Reviews` is towards the `Users`, rather than the `Tasks`, because it is the `Users'` workmanship.

I have this query:

```
rq = from r in Review,
  where: r.module_type == "users",
  where: r.module_id == ^user_id,
  group_by: r.module_id,
  select: avg(r.stars)

t =
  Repo.get_by(Task, id: task_id)
  |> Repo.preload(user: [reviews: rq])
```

Obviously, I am getting an error:

> undefined function user_id/0

My question is, how can I pass the `user_id` from prelaoded user into `rq` the subquery?

I know we can use tuple in the preload to put more details. But I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: could you please also mention the relationship between these three tables?

Comment: @TabKey I updated with the relationship of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. If the value in the preloads list should be a query, like you've done, ecto will automatically add the correct filter by itself.

Comment: the case here is different, as my `user_id` is the reviewer is, but what i need is for the `user_id` to map to `module_id` (reviewee). Ended up, my solution is to do another loop to get the reviews separately.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your rewiews schema has 2 references to the users schema? In that case you can define that relation in the ecto schema of user as well, so you have 2 different ones, say written_reviews and received_reviews. Depending on which relation you're interested in, you could either preload written_reviews or received_reviews.